# Upper bound to floor of log

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

What's a good upper bound to the floor of the base k log function?
i.e:
$$ \lfloor \log_k(x)\rfloor\leq f(x)$$
By good I mean a rational function that grows slowly. My first attempt was $f(x)=\frac{x}{k^2}+1$.

Comment: In fact all rational bounds on the $\log$ function are terrible.

Comment: @kimchilover Anything better than the one I posted would do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending kimchi lover's answer,
you can use the
Taylor series expansion
as far as you want.

If
$f(x) = \log_k(x)$,
then
$f'(x) = \frac1{x\ln k}$,
$f''(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2\ln k}$,
$f'''(x) = \frac{2}{x^3\ln k}$,
and so on, with
$f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{x^n\ln k}$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+\dfrac{(x-a)^2f''(a)}{2}+\dfrac{(x-a)^3f'''(a)}{6}
+...\\
&=\log_k(a)+\dfrac{(x-a)}{a\ln k}-\dfrac{(x-a)^2}{2a^2\ln k}+\dfrac{(x-a)^3}{6a^3\ln k}
+...\\
&=\log_k(a)+\dfrac{(x-a)}{a\ln k}\left(1-\dfrac{x-a}{2a}+\dfrac{(x-a)^2}{6a^2}
+...\right)\\
&=\log_k(a)+\dfrac{(x-a)}{a\ln k} \left(\sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^j(x-a)^j}{(j+1)!a^{j}}+...\right)
\qquad\text{for any }n\\
\end{array}
$

Note that successive sums
are above and below the
actual value,
so you can get
upper and lower bounds.

Comment: These lower bounds cannot be true for very small $x$, as $\lim_{x\downarrow 0}\log x  =-\infty$ and your stated lower bounds are finite as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that $\log$ is concave to get $$\log_k x \le \log_k A + (x-A)/(A \ln k)$$ for any $A>0.$  This bound is possibly useful for $x$ close to $A$, but for $x$ far from $A$, it is terrible.  So if there is a range of $x$ values where your bound is supposed to do you the most good, pick $A$ in it.